# b2 doesn't recognize zlib

Tags: software-installation, compiling, c++, boost, zlib

I have a hard time compiling some program.

```
error: undefined reference to 'boost::iostreams::zlib::best_speed
```

So I am trying to build boost 1.72.0 on Ubuntu 19.10

```
$ ./b2

Building the Boost C++ Libraries.


- zlib                     : no  (cached)
- bzip2                    : yes (cached)
```

But it appears I already have zlib.

```
$ apt show zlib1g
Package: zlib1g
Version: 1:1.2.11.dfsg-1ubuntu3
$ apt show zlib1g-dev
Package: zlib1g-dev
Version: 1:1.2.11.dfsg-1ubuntu3
```

Can I somehow explicitly pass a path to zlib to b2?

I have a header in my system:

```
$ find /usr/include -name "zlib.h"
/usr/include/zlib.h
```

Comment: The zlib *development* package is `zlib1g-dev`

Comment: You are right, but it also appears i have it.

Comment: You ever get this to work? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

For more predictable results you have to install all needed build-dependencies for current version of [Boost](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/eoan/boost1.67) package by running

```
sudo apt-get build-dep boost1.67
```

and then try to compile the newest.

Comment: I did it and reverted to boost1.67. Problem persists, unfortunately.